# regex for numbers with possible digits after dot or comma in text

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, regex-group, postgres-9.6

I need a regex that can filter out numbers that might have digits after the dot from a text.

[(?:[A-Z]*\s*)(\d+)((.|,)(\d+))?](https://regex101.com/r/ROtnvR/1)

```
Text : Expected results : Actual Results
H 24    : 24            : 24
24.5    : 24.5          : 24
24,5    : 24.5          : 24
test5   : 5             : 5
test 5.5: 5.5           : 5
50.752  : 50.752        : 50
```

For some reason PG only returns the first group of my match. Can someone help me please.

```
select substring('test 5.5', cast('(?:[A-Z]*\s*)(\d+)((.|,)(\d+))?' as character varying)) as convertedvalue
```

Comment: So, do not use capturing groups, `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?`

Comment: Without capturing groups I don't get anything, just null. If you know of a function that handles the regex property, please give me the right function.

Comment: `regexp_match` or `regexp_matches`. Eg. `SELECT regexp_match('test 5.5', '\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?');`

Comment: they return null if I remove the groups

Comment: What is the PostgreSQL version?

Comment: Hmm works if I cast the parameters to character varying. Add your comment as answer so I can accept

Comment: You might have some specific settings, try doubling backslashes or `SELECT regexp_match('test 5.5', '[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)?');`

Comment: @NicoHaegens . . . Do you really intend to replace commas with periods or is that a typo in the question?  There is no reference to wanting to do such a replacement anywhere else in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of `substring()` and `replace()`, like:

```
select x, replace(substring(x, '(\d+(.|,)*\d*)'), ',', '.') convertedvalue
```

`substring()` captures the relevant part of the string, then `replace()` replaces the `,` with `.` if needed.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2c7f93eb8546654e89f9bf218c5552bc)**

```
with t(x) as ( values ('H 24'), ('24.5'), ('24,5'), ('test5'), ('test 5.5'), ('50.752') )
select x, replace(substring(x, '(\d+(.|,)*\d*)'), ',', '.') convertedvalue
from t
```

```
x        | convertedvalue
:------- | :-------------
H 24     | 24            
24.5     | 24.5          
24,5     | 24.5          
test5    | 5             
test 5.5 | 5.5           
50.752   | 50.752
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to use `substring()` for this:

```
with t(x) as (
       values ('H 24'),
              ('24.5'),
              ('24,5'), 
              ('test5'),
              ('test 5.5'), 
              ('50.752'),
              ('50.,752'),
              ('H50.12,')
      )
select x, substring(x, '[0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]*') as convertedvalue
from t;
```

Note that this handles cases such as the last two examples in the CTE.

If you want to replace `','`s with `'.'`, then you can use an additional `replace()` afterwards.

Comment: Does this replace `,` with `.`, like `24,5 => 24.5`?